# Is there a way to resize images in Django via imagename.230x150.jpg?

Tags: python, django

There's a nice plugin for Frog CMS that lets you just type in yourpicture.120x120.jpg or whatever, and it will automatically use the image in that dimension. If it doesn't exist, it creates it and adds it to the filesystem.

http://www.naehrstoff.ch/code/image-resize-for-frog

I was wondering if there's anything like this in Django/Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this snippet is close to what you need: [Dynamic thumbnail generator](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/619/)

You might also want to investigate [sorl-thumbnail](http://code.google.com/p/sorl-thumbnail/) which, even though it codes the thumbnail dimensions in the template instead of the URL, is more flexible/powerful.

Comment: sorl can do thumbnails in the filename too.

Comment: Oh thanks Andy.  That's what I get for just going from memory and not checking the docs :)